# Can not upload a file to the app store with Bitcode disable in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, bitcode

My project exported from the program Unity 5.3.3 to Xcode 7. Size increases significantly compared to the version of android. From 60 mg to 180 mb when the option Bitcode is enabled. When it is disabled it is on 70mg as a file size. But when trying to upload the file to the app store will not let me.
iTunes error operation failed appears .
When I enable Bitcode let me upload the file but with the size of 180mg, which is excessive.

I hope you can tell me how I can disable the Bitcode without error to upload the file to the app store

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Click Project in Target Section
2. Go To Build Setting
3. Search text Bitcode in search bar at top 
4. Set Yes to No for the Enable Bitcode
```